# como sumar filas de una matriz de 3x3, c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas estoy comenzando esto de c# y pues me gustaria que me indiquen que puedo corregir para que se sumen las filas de la matriz de 3x3, ya que solo me suma la primera fila y las demas no.

```
        int[,] nm = new int[3, 3];
        int suma = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            { 
            
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                nm[i, j] = Convert.ToInt16(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese valores: "));

            }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
            {
                
                for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
                {
                    suma += nm[i, j];

                }
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                
                for (int j = 2; j <= 2; j++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(suma.ToString());
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ni idea qué hará button2, pero ese ciclo `for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)` está rarísimo porque `i` arranca en `0`, pero se ejecuta mientras sea menor o igual QUE CERO, lo que da un total de UNA iteración para `i`. ¿Será ese el problema?

Comment: Es ese el problema, no tengas dudas. Suma solo cuando i es igual a cero como bien decís, lo cual es la primer fila como indica en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

si redefines suma como un arreglo de enteros con 3 elementos puedes cambiar:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                suma[i] += nm[i, j];

            }
        }
    }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(suma[i].ToString());
            }
        }
```